# How can I geo target ads/banners with javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ads, banner, geotargetting

Do you know of any way to do it? real example...?

I am looking for a free service like maxmind or others (I really don't care what) and I would like to have a different ad for US visitors.

Thanks a lot!

2astalavista: Your example works fine. This is what I did and it's still not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Geo Test</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
        function(data){            
            console.log(data);
            var c = data.countryCode;
            if(c=="US" || c=="US" ){
                document.getElementById('ddd').innerHTML = 'US'; } else {
                    document.getElementById('ddd').innerHTML = 'Not US';}
            /*
            this service needs ip
            var ip = data.host;
            alert(ip);
            $.getJSON( "http://freegeoip.net/json/"+ip,
                function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            );*/
        }
    );

});?
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ddd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't know if it's the server (amazon) or the CDN (cotendo)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these: http://freegeoip.net/static/index.html and http://smart-ip.net

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/UHgu4/5/):

```
$.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
    function(data){
        var c = data.countryCode;
        if(c=="US" || c=="USA" )
            alert("American visitor!");else
                alert("Not american visitor! ("+c+")");
    }
);
```

---

Why is your code not working?

1) You should take care of the error messages:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

[image]

remove `?`

2) error again:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

this means jquery does not work for some reason.

fix include link according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441429/669677)!

now it works :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Geo Test</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
        function(data){            
            console.log(data);
            var c = data.countryCode;
            if(c=="US" || c=="US" ){
                document.getElementById('ddd').innerHTML = 'US'; } else {
                    document.getElementById('ddd').innerHTML = 'Not US';}
        }
    );

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ddd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried to do this: not working :(

<script>
$.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
    function(data){
        var c = data.countryCode;
        if(c=="US" || c=="USA" ){
            document.write("Code Of Banner N1")
  } else {
            document.write("Code Of Banner N2")
  }
);
</script>

Comment: it is working, see the example I have linked (http://jsfiddle.net/UHgu4/5/). You need jquery to run this code.

Comment: Tried your example and it works great. Don't know why it's not working on my site/server - I'm using Amazon EC2 and Cotendo CDN. @2astalavista

Comment: This thing - @2astalavista, doesn't seem to be working. Am I right?