# Dynamically display Banners based on the countries where are visitors are visiting from

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, geotargetting

I have two sets of banners for two different locations and I want one set of banners to load when some one from the country visits the site and then other set to load in another country.

I do not know if this kind of Geo Targeting is possible, but I am using HTML 5, javascript and AJAX to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I geo target ads/banners with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996961/how-can-i-geo-target-ads-banners-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use eg. the IP Geolocation service by MaxMind. They offer a free version of their database which is quite accurate, within reason. http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing

It would be easy to accomplish on the server-side by looking the client's IP up in the database and displaying alternate content based on the result.