# Is there a hotlink for Google API to return the most current jQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a link to the “latest” jquery library on Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis)

So instead of including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script></pre>
```

You would have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/current/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The google tag is ironic

Comment: This has already been answered, [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis