# Trying to include datetimepicker on Website. What is the error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used to have a working datetimepicker on my website, but now it was stopped working. I found the js I was referencing was taken down. I went to the page and downloaded the js and stored it locally on my server.

Here is where I get the js from:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I import jquery and jquery ui before datetimepicker:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop' datetimepicker.js:387
```

Should this method come from the jquery-ui and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using latest version of jQuery.js and jQueryUI.js

The reason is **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method added only from jQuery1.6 but you are using 1.5

Comment: ok, that's weird it used to work but maybe the js changed that I was referencing. Seems to work with this:    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  any idea how to reference the latest jquery-ui?

Comment: From <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> and  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: do you know of a repository where there is something like jquery-ui-latest.min.js? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Comment: yes, I have that for jquery, but I was wondering about jquery-ui.

Answer (score 0):

> Should this method come from the jquery-ui

No. It comes from the script available at the page you linked to.

> and how can I fix this?

Download and include that script