# How to set focus on user control textbox in aspx page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls, textbox

How can I set focus on asp:TextBox which is placed inside a user control by using jquery/JavaScript function in aspx page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and use [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method. For using jQuery you need to [include jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis) and ensure your element is available in `DOM` before you access it. You can use [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for that.

```
$('#txt1').focus();
```

Or using plain JavaScript, [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus)

```
document.getElementById('txt1').focus();
```

If you do not have ClientIDMode = static then you will need to use ClientID

```
$('#<%= txt1.Client %>').focus();
```

Comment: You might need to use ClientID, make sure you replace txt1 with your control id.

Comment: Adil i also tried "$('#<%= txt1.Client %>').focus();" as u said in the above response but its giving same error,according to me its not able to find textbox with the given id and thats why its giving that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with jQuery :

```
$('#txt').focus();
```

Comment: You have to replace "#txt" with the real ID of the control to focus. ie: `$('#<%= txt.ClientID %>').focus();` if your asp control has the name `txt`

Comment: yeah i replaced "#txt" with my textbox id and also tried "$('#<%= txt.ClientID %>').focus();", however the error still persists.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function myfocus2() {
        $('#<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').focus();
    }
</script>
<div>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click1" />
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!--i'm calling the javascript function "myfocus2()" from Button2 on click event.-->

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfocus2() {
 $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').focus();
}
```

There should be no space between `=` and `TextBox2`.