# How to show text in div, when text enter in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

When Text Enter in Textarea then show text in DIV.but Condition is that,i append mutiple DIV then type text in Textare.then show text only one DIV not Other DIV.

My Code :

```
<button data-bind="adds">ADD</button>
     <div data-bind="foreach: items">
                <div class="SpeechBubble" id="speechID" data-bind="attr: { class: 'SpeechBubble' }">
                <div class="pointer bottom " id="pointer"></div>
                <div class="txtspeech"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

var SpeechBubble = function () {
                this.items = ko.observableArray();
                this.adds = function (item) {
                    this.items.push(item);
                }
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new SpeechBubble());



$('.speechttxt').keyup(function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('.txtspeech').html(txt);
});
```

Comment: How do you determine which `div` to change the text of?

Comment: when i append first one div then type text in textarea show in DIV.

Comment: Right, but if you append again, which div should be changed? The previous one, or the new one?

Comment: how to short-out this problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working your probably need to put it [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so that when the script for binding event is execute the element you are looking for is added to `DOM` and [include jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XQWVq/)**

```
$('.speechttxt').keyup(function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('.txtspeech').html(txt);
});
```

You can add jQuery using script tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>    

<script  type="text/javascript">
    document.ready(function(){
        $('.speechttxt').keyup(function () {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            $('.txtspeech').html(txt);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: its OK but problem is that, there are mutiple DIV append.then type text show one DIV. then type text Show another DIV...

Comment: You can use id of you want to show in one div. or you can use index for particular div $('.txtspeech').eq(0).html(txt);

Comment: There Are No Response..Here.!!

Answer (score 0):

add the class 'txtspeech' to div you want to display the text