# jQuery not working on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried using jQuery on my website, but it did not seem to work. I figured I was doing something wrong, so I tried copying a codecademy lesson that I completed onto a test site. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Codecademy Lesson</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/elevator.png"/>   
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
position: absolute;
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').animate({top:'+=100px'},1000)
});
```

Is someone able to tell me why this code is not working?
My browser is Chrome and I have the latest version.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: What *should* it do? What *does* it do? What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/qxbWd/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/t4x5t/

Comment: Yes I am testing this locally via file:///C:/ etc...

Comment: @Adrift, good point, but rather don't change it, but use a real webserver instead. You can still use a local, lightweight webserver as long as you test over HTTP instead of local files. Any WAMP/LAMP/XAMP configuration will do and you can even find more lightweight alternatives if you like. I'm using http://www.wampserver.com/en/ and I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: because jsfiddle imports correct and OP doesn't

Comment: What is wrong?   Seems to be working...   Unless It is supposed to do something magic your not telling us about...   http://jsfiddle.net/QAZe7/

Comment: @user2826739 then this statement is false *"I tried using jQuery on my website"* `file://` isn't your website, it's your filesystem.

Comment: Sorry, this is supposed to make the image go Down 100px when the document is ready.

Comment: Should I add it to my online website then and test it there? will it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that will make a large difference.

Comment: You can install local web server software as well. Or use a tool like Netbeans that you can configure to automatically upload files as soon as you save them.

Comment: It works on my live website. Thank you

Comment: you should never miss Jquery Library, all the scripts works on top of that jquery Library Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Answer (score 6):

You need to Download the jquery Library and save your local files You can download it from

http://jqueryui.com/

or

you have to use this link

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

or for the minified version

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js - Version 1.9.1 family, Google hosted

You can refer this also

[Is there a link to the "latest" jQuery library on Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis)

Comment: @Philipp Sander Thanks fro the edit for the minified version

Comment: no problem! i thought i add it, because minified is used in the original code of the question

Answer (score 2):

The image won't be loaded by the time `document.ready` is fired, better use `window.load` so you can see your effect in action, so replace your following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

for this one:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```