# when the slideshow changes image refresh my page

Tags: jquery, html

I am new at jQuery and I'm trying to create a slideshow.
I created it but when the timer change my picture, all the page seems to be refreshed.

*HTML Example*:

```
<div class="slide">
    <img id="scroll_image" src="img/rooms/suite5.jpg" width="1000" height="350" alt="hotel-suite-1" class="show" />
    <img id="scroll_image" src="img/rooms/suite1.jpg" width="1000" height="350" alt="hotel-suite-2" />
    <img id="scroll_image" src="img/rooms/suite2.jpg" width="1000" height="350" alt="hotel-suite-3" />
    <img id="scroll_image" src="img/rooms/suite3.jpg" width="1000" height="350" alt="hotel-suite-4" />
    <img id="scroll_image" src="img/rooms/suite4.jpg" width="1000" height="350" alt="hotel-suite-5" />
</div><!--end of slide-->
```

*jQuery Example*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {
    var current = $('.slide .show');
    var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.parent().children(':first');
    current.hide().removeClass('show');
    next.fadeIn().addClass('show');
    setTimeout(slideShow, 6000);
}
```

You can see what i mean if you [click here](http://www.delmar.gr/demo), scroll down the page and wait for the timer to change the image!?

Comment: You should take the time to format the code in your question or others wont find the time to answer.

Comment: What browser are you using ? Anyway why don't you use JQuery cycle plugin ?Is much easier to use:)

Comment: @JamieRead Sorry for the bad code but i didnt know that i can format it here. Its first time here. Thanks for replying me.

Comment: @Zsigoveny As for the browser iam using chrome but i test it at firefox also and do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your page that is refreshing. Your page is for some reason srolling everytime you slide a image.

Your problem is the jquery-min-1.5.1.js you are using.

[Update your jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) to the latest version and the problem will be solved :) You can also use the latest external jquery link:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

source : [Is there a link to the "latest" jQuery library on Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis)

---

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTcG6/)** With your jQuery version

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTcG6/1/)** With latest version (used the latest external link as shown above)

Goodluck!

Comment: i cant vote. To vote up i need at least 15 reputation. Your solution really works

Comment: I accept now? Its my first time here and i dont know if i do things right.

Comment: Hehe no problem :) yea you have accepted this answer. I'm just glad i could help :) Goodluck further on!