# How to open 1 div on mouse hover of second div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to open one div on mouse hover of second div.
The div 1 is display is none by default but when user hover on div 2 the div 1 will be displayed.
But it's not working.
My code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

    <style>
        .testtmpblock{
            display: none;
            background-color: black;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .tmpd{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('mouseenter', '.tmpd', function () {
                $(this).find(".testtmpblock").show();
            }).on('mouseleave', '.tmpd', function () {
                $(this).find(".testtmpblock").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tmpd">
    kjkjkj
</div>
<div class="testtmpblock">
    data
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`div testtmpblock` will be appear on hover of `div tmpd` but it's not working.

I have also write Script for it.
Any guidance that where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `next` instead of `find` as find is used for desendants and your required element is not descendant.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/4987s/)**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.tmpd', function () {
          $(this).next(".testtmpblock").show();
      }).on('mouseleave', '.tmpd', function () {
          $(this).next(".testtmpblock").hide();
      });
  });
```

You can avoid next if only *single* element has class `testtmpblock`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.tmpd', function () {
          $(".testtmpblock").show();
      }).on('mouseleave', '.tmpd', function () {
          $(".testtmpblock").hide();
      });
});
```

Comment: That's work for me. I have also tried on fiddle. Thank You so much sir. Now I ll have call servlet in that div that display on hover. any idea sir how to do it ?

Comment: You are welcome, your will need to use ajax your can try using jQuery ajax, this may help, http://www.programming-free.com/2012/08/ajax-with-jsp-and-servlet-using-jquery.html

Comment: @elclanrs - that's also pretty good.. Simply awesome and shows code optimisation. Thank You to also.

Comment: @Adil - Sir do you use TeamViewer ? Your Code works on fiddle but when I am trying it on my pc it's not working.

Comment: Check if you included jQuery in your page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Comment: Yes I have added but I have miss to close the </script> tag in that so after that the function script is not executed. but right now I have solved it.

Comment: Thank You Sir, Sir is it possible to add servlet in `<jsp:include page="vcart.jsp"></jsp:include>` right now I have added file vcart.jsp that works fine but data will loaded in it when my showcart servlet file executed then it redirect to vcart.jsp and then data display, so is it possible to add servlet something like that. above include code i have added in `.testtmpblock div.`

Comment: Its very long I used to work in JSP/Servlet so not sure how we can use it. Servlet will generate html you can use that html here. Could be the id of top most html element generated by servlet. Posting a new question may get you sooner answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the divs are next to each other you do this with CSS only:

```
.testtmpblock {
  display: none;
}

.tmpd:hover ~ .testtmpblock {
  display: block;
}
```

If you want to animate it you can use CSS3 transitions.

99% of time you can get away with CSS only, and the animations will be faster with transitions. It's all about how you handle the markup. If you make the hidden element a child then it's always doable with just CSS, for example:

```
<div class="tmpd">
  kjkjkj
  <div class="testtmpblock">
    data
  </div>
</div>
```

And you'd use a selector like so:

```
.tmpd:hover .testtmpblock {}
```

Answer (score 1):

try **[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter', '.tmpd', function () {
                $(this).next(".testtmpblock").show();
            }).on('mouseleave', '.tmpd', function () {
                $(this).next(".testtmpblock").hide();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('hover','.tmpd', function () {
            $(".testtmpblock").show();
        }, function () {
            $(".testtmpblock").hide();
        }
    );
 });
```

Comment: It shows me an error at line last that multiple annotation found.