# Get value of textbox input: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form input that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="params[well]" id="params_well" value="#f8f8f8" placeholder="#rrggbb" class="minicolors minicolors-input" data-position="right" data-control="hue" size="7" maxlength="7">
```

and javascript like this:

```
var params_well = $("#params_well").val();
```

and getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of null

I really cant proceed with anything else till i figure this out

Comment: do you have another js library

Comment: what are the js libraries added to the page

Comment: try `var params_well = jQuery("#params_well").val();`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the jQuery is integrated correctly, you probably trying to access before element is being added to DOM. Your code is working fine.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bV6bh/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var params_well = $("#params_well").val();
});
```

You can include jQuery using script tag, also worth going through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis).

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Im using Joomla and am now getting Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'

Comment: already loaded via <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: It seems you do not have added jQuery successfully. verify the path. Showing complete javascript could help understanding reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var params_well = $("#params_well").val();
});
```

Or put this on bottom of your page

```
var params_well = $("#params_well").val();
```