# How to remove the background color in select option tag with reset button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

When I am clicking reset, the background color in select field is not changing to white. Its displaying the color of the last selected option. Please help me out with this problem.
I want to remove the background color too when I am clicking reset button. Thanks in advance for your help..

```
<body>
<form>

<input type="reset" class="resetButton" />
<select id="select" style="color: white; width:60px;"onchange="changecolor(select,value)">
<option value="white" style="background-color: white; "></option>
<option value="red" style="background-color: red; color: white;">AB</option>
<option value="blue" style="background-color: blue; color: white;">BC</option>
<option value="green" style="background-color: green; color: white;">CD</option>
<option value="orange" style="background-color: orange; color: white;">DE</option>
</select>

</form>
</body>


<script>
$(function()
{
    $('.resetButton').click(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('form').find('select').each(function()
        {
             $(this)[0].selectedIndex=0;


        });
    });
});
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changecolor(id,color){
id.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
 $('.resetButton').click(function()
{
    $(this).closest('form').find('select').each(function()
    {
         $(this)[0].selectedIndex=0;
         changecolor($(this).attr('id'),'white');

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Milind, Thanks for your answer. Its still not working on my page. Please try this code in some other editor like W3schools tryit Editor, its still showing the previous background color.

Comment: can you give me the link that have select and button to click in it.

Comment: Hi, just copy your and mine code in w3schools editor http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select   and please check it. Its not removing the background color. Thanks

Comment: <body>
<form>

<input type="reset" class="resetButton" />
<select id="select" style="color: white; width:60px;"onchange="changecolor(select,value)">
<option value="white" style="background-color: white; "></option>
<option value="red" style="background-color: red; color: white;">AB</option>
<option value="blue" style="background-color: blue; color: white;">BC</option>
<option value="green" style="background-color: green; color: white;">CD</option>
<option value="orange" style="background-color: orange; color: white;">DE</option>
</select>

</form>
</body>

Comment: anton has given the link above to fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/q8xA3/4/).  just copy the code and run in w3school editor.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $('.resetButton').click(function()
{
    $(this).closest('form').find('select').each(function()
    {
         $(this)[0].selectedIndex=0;
         changecolor($(this).attr('id'),'white');

    });
});

function changecolor(id,color){
id.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
</script>

Comment: One more doubt Milind. Anton is calling one more .js file in source. <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>  Is it better to use reference from some other source.

Comment: That is jquery library.You need to include that in page if you wish using jquery code

Comment: Ok. I am beginner to javascript and sorry to bother you again. If I include that link in my code, is there a chance that the library link may change in future and if so happens then my code may not work again.

Comment: Ohh... you definetely need to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Comment: Milind its not working on my page. Here is the link to my page http://crm.addbola.com/index.php/help please check this out. Thanks

Comment: Hi Milind, sorry to bother you again. The code is working fine on my friends laptop but its not working on mine.

Comment: try downloading same browser on both machine and then run the code on both browser.

Comment: I tried that too..I am using mozilla 26.0 and my friend too using same. I have tried in mozilla, chrome and IE but the problem persist. My friend also tried in these three browsers and its working fine with 1 or 2 page refreshs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.css('background',color)` to do this

[Check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/33/)