# Rails, JQuery: onClick event not attaching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I'm missing out on some fundamental aspect of how Javascript is handled by Rails.

I created a new Rails project using Ruby 2.1.0.

```
$ mkdir whatishappening
$ cd whatishappening
$ rails new .
$ rails generate scaffold post title body:text
$ rails db:migrate
$ rails server
```

I then proceeded to create a test post.  After that I added:

*whatishappening/app/views/posts/show.html.erb*

```
<a href="#" id="foo">link</a>
```

*whatishappening/app/assets/javascripts/posts.js* (I renamed this from *posts.js.coffee*)

```
console.log("posts.js loaded");

$("#foo").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log("link clicked");
});
```

When I run via `rails server` and monitor the Javascript console in Chrome, I see:

```
> posts.js loaded
```

However, I don't see

`> link clicked`

when I click the link.

Can someone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the answer from @Adil and the tip from @Monk_Code, I found the following the be the best solution considering that the default Rails 4 install includes Turbolinks.

*app/assets/javascripts/posts.js*

```
console.log("posts.js loaded");

var ready;
ready = function() {

  $("#foo").on("click", function(event) {
    console.log("link clicked");
  });

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check two things.

- You added jQuery successfully, you can find how to added jQuery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis).
- Your binding code executes when foo is added to DOM, you can use [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure that.

  ```
  console.log("posts.js loaded");

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#foo").on("click", function(event) {
      console.log("link clicked");
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: you need `$(document).on('page:load', ready)` if you use `turbo-links`

Comment: if you use `turbo-links` you need not only @Monk_Code's code (useful tip sure) but also you need to read this article http://staal.io/blog/2013/01/18/dangers-of-turbolinks/