# Raise jQuery click event on every td in tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-click-event

I'm trying to raise a click event whenever a user clicks on any `td` element inside the `tbody`.This is what I have so far but it's not raising the event, any ideas why?

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#skuOptionsBody td").click(function () {
            alert('clicked!');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table id="options" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    SWEET OPTION
                </td>
                <td>
                    DRINK OPTION
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="skuOptionsBody">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    SO1
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    DO1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I forgot to mention that I dynamically add rows to the table using jQuery and as I'm adding new rows I need them to be bound to this click event.How can this be done?

Comment: Did you tried live event in jquery. Event on dynamically added HTML will not work itself. Either use Live or On event in jquery..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this inside $(document).ready(function(){});

```
$("#skuOptionsBody td").bind('click', function () {
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

OR for jquery > 1.7 you can make use of .on()

```
$("#skuOptionsBody").on('click', 'td', function () {
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be in a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) because you are trying to add the event handlers before the target elements are loaded in the dom

```
jQuery(function(){
        $("#skuOptionsBody td").click(function () {
            alert('clicked!');
        });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The script for binding executes before elements added to dom, Also use the [latest jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis) if possible.

- You can put script in document.ready

  ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#skuOptionsBody td").click(function () {
            alert('clicked!');
         });
   });
  ```
- Use delegated events using on

  ```
     $(document).on("click","#skuOptionsBody td", function () {
        alert('clicked!');
     });
  ```
- Put the script after html elements added to DOM, could be just before ending body tag.

  ```
    <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <table id="options" border="1">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          SWEET OPTION
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          DRINK OPTION
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="skuOptionsBody">
                  <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: center">
                          SO1
                      </td>
                      <td style="text-align: center">
                          DO1
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $("#skuOptionsBody td").click(function () {
          alert('clicked!');
          });
      </script>
  </body>
  ```

Comment: OP is using `jquery-1.4.1`, as you already know it was added in version added: 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Warp your code in [**document-ready handler**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) because when the code runs it won't find the *"skuOptionsBody td"* element in the page: the browser will not have parsed that yet.

*Code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#skuOptionsBody td").click(function () {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
});
```

**OR**

Move your `<script>` tag to the end of the `<body>`.

**OR**

Use Event Delegation

*Code*

```
$(document).delegate('click', "#skuOptionsBody td", function () {
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your code. It is just that you have not added it at correct place. write the code on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#skuOptionsBody td").click(function () {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in jsfiddle and everything seems to be working fine, just put it to some top event, like $(document).ready() function. Heres a link http://jsfiddle.net/lithium182/A5vMj/

jquery:

```
$("#skuOptionsBody td").click(function () {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
```

You want to trigger click on a thead cell?