# TypeError: $(...).layout is not a function

Tags: jquery

**i added necessary jquery files and running in firefox browser **

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //This code is for tcgform resiz
    var myLayout; // a var is required because this page utilizes: myLayout.allowOverflow() method


        myLayout = $('body').layout({

        west__showOverflowOnHover:true});
});
```

Comment: Show us the includes.

Comment: You are not including plugin before using it or wrong plugin path or...

Comment: jQuery [does not seem to have a `layout` method](http://api.jquery.com/?s=layout).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario he might be using a plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Is that $.layout a jQuery plugin? The error means that the function is unknown, therefore the source file has not been loaded or you are calling the function before the plugin is loaded.

Comment: Which .js file it require

Comment: @user3507997 show us your includes, we won't be able to help you without them

Comment: I don't know, where have you seen that layout plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the jQuery script.
Download and include or include from internet like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(From [Is there a link to the "latest" jQuery library on Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis))

OR like here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: Doesn't matter, `$(..).layout` does not come with jQuery.