# Programatically get the jQuery version numbers hosted on Google CDN

Tags: jquery, workflow, frontend, google-cdn

Is there a service that will return the version numbers of jQuery that are hosted on Google? They are posted on their [webpage](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery), but is there a way to get that data without parsing the page text?

I want to automatically link to the latest 1.x release when scaffolding a new project (not link to the latest version on production sites).

Thanks.

Comment: Just use this: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply link to the "`1.x`" family:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

...and parse out the version from the beginning of that file:

```
/*! jQuery v1.11.
```