# javascript code working in jsfiddle but not working in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

my code is working in jsfiddle but not working in the browser i dont know what i missed here could you please check it and tell me the solution. i  google it but i am not getting correct solution please help me 
this is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/pLTrJ/9/

```
   <!doctype html>
     <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"  type="text/javascript">   </script>
      </head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var random = 0;
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("showVal");
        updateTheDiv(9,0);
        function updateTheDiv(inRange, inMin) {
        random = (Math.random()*inRange+inMin)|0; 
        theDiv.innerHTML = random;
        var nextCall = (Math.random()*1000)|0;
        setTimeout(function() {
        updateTheDiv(inRange, inMin);
            }, nextCall);
        }
      </script>
        <body>
          <div id="showVal"></div>
        </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Are there errors in the console? What is your expected output?

Comment: Do not use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js, it will always refer to jquery 1.11.1! Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Comment: @Andy can you check this link http://jsfiddle.net/pLTrJ/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jsfiddle has wrapped it automatically in the `onload` event.  You haven't done this in your HTML page, so when it runs in the browser you're trying to get hold of the div before it's been rendered, so `theDiv` is null.

The below should work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var random = 0;
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("showVal");
        updateTheDiv(9, 0);
        function updateTheDiv(inRange, inMin) {
            random = (Math.random() * inRange + inMin) | 0;
            theDiv.innerHTML = random;
            var nextCall = (Math.random() * 1000) | 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                updateTheDiv(inRange, inMin);
            }, nextCall);
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="showVal">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could also mention `$(document).ready();`, in line with using jquery.

Comment: I could, but the only reference to jQuery is the included script - it's not actually been used anywhere, nor tagged in the question

Comment: @JamesThorpe thank you so much james i got it , but one thing i did not understand what you mean $(document).ready();

Comment: If you _do_ want to use jQuery, the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event handler can be used instead of directly using `window.onload` and allows for multiple handlers to be bound to the event more easily

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Browser ;)

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"  type="text/javascript">   </script>
  </head>

    <body>
      <div id="showVal"></div>
    </body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var random = 0;
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("showVal");
    updateTheDiv(9,0);
    function updateTheDiv(inRange, inMin) {
    random = (Math.random()*inRange+inMin)|0; 
    theDiv.innerHTML = random;
    var nextCall = (Math.random()*1000)|0;
    setTimeout(function() {
    updateTheDiv(inRange, inMin);
        }, nextCall);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

(I just put the script to the bottom. So the script loads after your element is set.)

Comment: i tried james answer it is working fine, your solution also working fine thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. His solution is better than mine. :-)