# How do i hide div in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 div which are:

`<div class="widgetbox" id="divone">Content 1</div>`

`<div class="widgetbox" id="divtwo">Content 2</div>`

`<div class="widgetbox" id="divthree">Content 3</div>`

I need to hide two of these div so that I can make a condition to decide which to appear and which to hide later on. I tried to hide it like below, but it doesn't work. I think I'm using mvc 4. sorry for bad english.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#divtwo").hide();
    $("#divthree").hide();    
</script>
```

Comment: Does your project have jQuery reference?

Comment: Define *"doesn't work"*. Does it throw an error? Does it work if you run those commands in the console after page-load? Where is your script-tag located in the HTML document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you get two answers:

1)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#divtwo").hide();
        $("#divthree").hide();
    });
</script>
```

2) try this one. No need any references.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById("divtwo").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("divthree").style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add jQuery reference. [Here you is way to get latest jQuery in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441429)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then your code will work for `.hide()`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#divtwo").hide();
    $("#divthree").hide();    
</script>
```