# How can I find if a span contains a specific word?

Tags: jquery

I have a span with a certain class and I want to check if it contains it and hide another element.

To be more specific I have:

```xml
<span class="border">0€</span>
<div class="pop">something</div>
```

I tried the code but unfortunately it does not work.

```
if ($(".border").html().indexOf("span") == 0€ ){
    $("div[name=pop]").hide()
}
```

Looking forward hearing from you.

Comment: Use XPath http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/ to search for all `span` elements with given class.

Answer (score 3):

The `indexOf` function returns the *index* and you can not compare it with string you are looking for *0€*.

```
if ($(".border").html().indexOf("0€") != -1 ){
```

You probably need text instead of html as this string is not expected as part of html.

```
if ($(".border").text().indexOf("0€") != -1 ){
```

**Edit** based on comments of OP that he added as an answer.

> TypeError: $ is not a function

You need to add the reference of jQuery in order to use jQuery function like `$` for which you are getting error. This question [Is there a link to the “latest” jQuery library on Google APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis) will show you have you can add `jQuery`.

[Is there a link to the "latest" jQuery library on Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-selector:

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
if ( $('.border:contains("0€")')
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to check if it contains specifically `0€`

```
if ( $('.border:contains(" 0€")') // This will not select 100€
```

Assuming there is space before `0€`

Comment: what if the value is `100€`

Comment: @ArunPJohny You can use `$('.border:contains("100€")'`

Comment: @Tushar, if the value is 100€, your code will return true.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Then `indexOf` will also not work, Please check my Update

Answer (score 0):

Don't use :contains() or indexOf() as it will fail in cases like `100€`

```
if ($("span.border").html().trim() == '0€') {
    $("div[name=pop]").hide()
}
```

Comment: OP did not state that he needed to check for cases like `100€` as well, just `0€`.