# Where to find the jquery library link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help to find the link to the jquery library so i can include it into my website. I searched on the [official website](http://jquery.com/) but there does not seem to be any info or it is not obvious enough.

There is only the possibility to download the jquery library, but i just need the link so i can include it. Where do i have to search?

I found two source links, but it seems like they are obsolete:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/ a cdn for various libraries for example <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a link to the "latest" jQuery library on Google APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis)

Comment: you are also missing `http:` in your link

Comment: @Pepo_rasta, but the link works so it makes no difference.

Comment: cdn stands for content delivery network https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy one of these 2 urls into your code. They are from MAXCDN.
Production: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js
Development: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js

Comment: Thank you. Which one should i choice? Production or Development?

Comment: No problem. Production if you are worried about decreasing file size. It removes all the spacing between the code to reduce the size of it. Use development if you are still working on your website or app. I personally always use the production version.

Comment: Thx. In my oppinion the official site should be beginner friendly, people should be able to find this info by themselves without much research.

Comment: Yeah, I saw where you looked. It used to be posted there, where you found the other ones. They moved it after they came out with the new version, I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

With this url you can get the latest versions jquery:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js 
or http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js for production