# @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js outdated: How to refer always the newest jquery library?

Tags: jquery, userscripts

See below

From a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script I want to refer/include always the newest jquery library.

Therefore I coded until now:

`// @require         http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`

Much to my surprise I experienced that this kind of reference is heavily outdated since it refers to v1.11.1

I want to avoid to code a version number in URL like

`// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js`

Is there no version independent URL for always automatically the latest jquery library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/441429/616443 and https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/